# Compare & Parse 2D array elements

Tags: java, arrays, compare, multidimensional-array, parseint

I am trying to parseDouble column 1. Afterwards, if elements in column 1 < 5 AND if elements in column 2 equal "yes" for the same row, then print out the corresponding row. I am trying to loop through each row and see if the criteria matches. The issue is that I keep getting nothing or this printed out instead of the row information: [Ljava.lang.String;@3b3c9741. Also, I get this error: cannot find symbol - variable parseDouble. Any suggestions are very much appreciated.

```
       String[][] input = new String[20][5];
       double d = Double.parseDouble[][0];  //parseDouble column 1

       for(int row=0; row<input.length; row++){
           for(int col=0; col<input[row].length;col++ ){
               if(input[row].length<5 && input[row].equals("yes"))
                   System.out.println(input[row]);
           }
       }
```

Comment: `System.out.println(budget[row])` is not actually a String, it is String[]. I notice your loop moves through rows but doesn't move through columns. If you want it to move through columns, your need to add another for-loop in the existing loop i.e. `for (int col =  0; col < input[row].length; col++) {... Another user Tirath has also suggested using Arrays.toString which may suit you better.

Answer (score 0):

First -

```
    Double.parseDouble[][0];    //is wrong
    Double.parseDouble("1")     //is proper
```

Above, you should notice that `parseDouble` method is defined to take a `String` type as an argument. In your case, you are missing the parenthesis also.

So, if I'm really trying very hard to make it work - I would have done something like

```
    Double.parseDouble([][0]);         //or
    Double.parseDouble(input[][0]);    //both usage are incorrect
```

See, below to understand how you should be using those indexes

```
    int[][] a = {{1, 2}, {3, 4}};
    //a[0] points to {1, 2}
    //a[1] points to {3, 4}
    //a[][0] is invalid
    //a[0][0] points to 1
    //a[0][1] points to 2
    //a[1][0] points to 3
    //a[1][1] points to 4
```

Now, modify the comparison `if(input[row].length<5 && input[row].equals("yes"))` to

```
if(input[row].length<5 && Arrays.toString(input[row]).replaceAll("\\[|\\]|,|\\s", "").equals("yes"))
//or for case insensitive comparison
if(input[row].length<5 && Arrays.toString(input[row]).replaceAll("\\[|\\]|,|\\s", "").equalsIgnoreCase("yes"))
```

When you say print `System.out.println(input[row])` - this means you are trying to print an array

Use `System.out.println(Arrays.toString(input[row]));` instead to print the array.

Comment: I implemented your suggestions, but nothing is printed on screen. And there are rows that satisfy the if statement.

Comment: Even with the "for case insensitive comparison", it doesn't change the result.

Comment: What is happening? You able to execute it fine but the result is not what you are expecting or you are getting some error?